# Clip raster using a shapefile of 5500 polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, clip

[image: Original raster]I have a nightlights raster file of India, and i want to clip it using the block shapefile for India. There are 5500 blocks. But I can't find a unique attribute(except for serial no.) to clip the raster with, I tried doing it using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10, but if I put the serial no. in "group by fields" there is no output(the rasters are generated but it is a blank image when i put it in arcmap). If I put some non-unique atribute, the model runs for sometime then shows error. 
[image: Extracted raster with the attribute table for one of the extracted rasters]

Comment: What precise error does it show?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screen shot of the model? Sounds like an extent issue to me?

Comment: I used the serial no. in the shapefile in "group by fields". It ran but the attribute table for the extracted files are the same as for the original raster(I have attached the attribute tables above). Can someone please explain if its a problem with the model I built? I couldn't post a screenshot of my model as the no. of images were limited. When I add the clip in the model window and join with the arrow a pop-up box comes where I click "output extent". Is that the problem?